# Is there a way in InDesign to quickly resize text that is stacked so that each line is the same width but different sizes?

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, text, font-design, font-size

I have a method currently of just going line by line and increasing the font size until it takes up the width of the text box and just readjusting the line/paragraph spacing but want to see if there's a shortcut to doing this on InDesign. Here's an example: [image]

Comment: In short: it's not possible natively. You'll have to do it manually. Or write a script that does that, or look for existing script. Have a look at this one: http://in-tools.com/article/scripts-blog/fun-with-text-fitting-in-indesign/

Answer (score 1):

Does "Justify All Lines" work for you?

Select your text in the text box and use the option in the paragraph menu.

(It works in InDesign CC, not sure about other versions).

[image: Align text from Adobe manual]

Comment: That only alters word and letter spacing, not font size; so no, that won’t work for what the question is about.